# SQL Server Simple example for the use of Delimiter in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, delimiter

Surprisingly there isn't any straight forward example to demonstrate the use of delimiter in Stored Procedure?

I have a string variable as input (with delimiter) and would like to make it as condition in Stored Procedure. Something like below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testing
(
    @stringVar    NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
)
....
BEGIN

    Select * from table where column not in (@stringVar)

.....
END
```

Sample value for `@stringVar` will be `a~b~c~d`

How should I handle such case? Is there any built-in delimiter function in Sql Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a bit of tricky situation and there is no "Simple way" of doing it. but I can give you the simplest way of doing it.

You will need to do two things to make this work,

> 1) Create a Split function which takes a parameter of deliminited
>   string and split these values.
>  2) Make your stored procedure in a
>   way that passed deliminited string is passed to that function and then
>   splited values are passed to the stored procedure

**Split Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FnSplit]
(
@List nvarchar(2000),
@SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)
RETURNS @RtnValue table (Id int identity(1,1),Value nvarchar(100))
AS
 BEGIN

  While(Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)>0)

   Begin

      Insert Into @RtnValue (value)
       Select Value = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)-1))) 

  Set @List = Substring(@List,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)+len(@SplitOn),len(@List))

  End

    Insert Into @RtnValue (Value)

   Select Value = ltrim(rtrim(@List))

  Return

END
```

**Your Proc**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testing
(
    @stringVar    NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
)
....
BEGIN

    Select * from table 
    where column not IN(SELECT Value 
                        FROM dbo.FnSplit(@stringVar,'~'))

.....
END
```

Answer (score 3):

From SQL Server 2008 on, you can use **table valued parameters**.

I cannot explain it better than here: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html

Answer (score 1):

There is n't any built-in delimiter function in Sql Server. You can use user defined table value function for this purpose.

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString]
(@pString varchar(max),@pSplitChar char(1))
returns @tblTemp table (tid int,value varchar(1000))
as
begin

    declare @vStartPosition     int
    declare @vSplitPosition     int
    declare @vSplitValue        varchar(1000)
    declare @vCounter       int
    set @vCounter=1

    select @vStartPosition = 1,@vSplitPosition=0

    set @vSplitPosition = charindex( @pSplitChar , @pString , @vStartPosition )
    if (@vSplitPosition=0 and len(@pString) != 0)
    begin
        INSERT INTO @tblTemp
            (
            tid     ,
            value   
            )
        VALUES
            (
            1   ,
            @pString        
            )
        return      --------------------------------------------------------------->>
    end
    set @pString=@pString+@pSplitChar
    while (@vSplitPosition > 0 )
    begin
        set @vSplitValue = substring( @pString , @vStartPosition , @vSplitPosition - @vStartPosition )
        set @vSplitValue = ltrim(rtrim(@vSplitValue))

        INSERT INTO @tblTemp
            (
            tid     ,
            value   
            )
        VALUES
            (
            @vCounter   ,
            @vSplitValue        
            )
        set @vCounter=@vCounter+1
        set @vStartPosition = @vSplitPosition + 1
        set @vSplitPosition = charindex( @pSplitChar , @pString , @vStartPosition )
    end

    return
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way of this. I would recomend reading [this](http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/split-string-to-table-using-transact-sql/) article.
You need to split your string progmaticly. There is no such function in sql.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of implementing split functions in SQL Server, with lots of different performance characteristics: some (ab)use the XML functionality of SQL server, some use Tally tables, some use the CLR *etc.* For a description of one of these methods and a performance comparison, I'd recommend you'd look at Jeff Moden's article on [SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) (registration required).

Once you have a table-valued splitter function available, you can implement your select simply:

```
select *
from MyTable t
where t.MyColumn not in (select Item from dbo.MySplit(@stringVar, '~') where Item is not null)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for testing existence then:

```
Select * from table where CHARINDEX('~'+column+'~' , '~'+@stringVar+'~' ,1)=0
```